# ClassCastException due to two class had same name in different aar

Tags: android, gradle

I ran into a strange issue in android development, a `ClassCastException` happened in running time when show my `XTextView`.
I have 2 modules and imported via aar, say `module_A` and `module_B`. Each of them has a `XTextView`, and a layout named `search_result`, and other stuff not relate so I omit here, and their structure looked like this:

```
module_A
  src...
    java
      XTextView.java
    res...
      search_result.xml
module_B
  src...
    java
      XTextView.java
    res...
      search_result.xml
```

Also these two `XTextView` has different package:
`com.module_A.XTextView`
`com.module_B.XTextView`

And `module_A` did not dependent on `module_B`, `module_B` did not dependent on `module_A`.

Then I set `module_A.search_result.xml` to `AResultAdapter`, whom is a recylcerView adapter to display the result elements with following code:

```
package com.module_A.search
AResultAdapter {
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ResultItemHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.search_result, parent, false)
    return ResultItemHolder(view)
  }
  
  
  class ResultItemHolder(parent:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(parent){
    val result:XTextView = parent.findViewById(R.id.x_text_view) // crash here
    // other implement
  }
}
```

And I use this adapter in `SearchActivit`y in `module_A`, and when I need to show search result, I just `startActivity` from any activity in app modules.

Then a `lassCastException` happened in `parent.findViewById(R.id.x_text_view)`, said:
**java.lang.ClassCastException: module_B.XTextView cannot be cast to module_A.XTextView**
Why did I get `module_B.XTextView` from `module_A.search_result.xml`. I assume it came from they have same layout and class name. But I can not modify the aar, so how can I work around and prevent render wrong layout?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you include your import statements?

Comment: @danartillaga did you mean the import of AReaultAdapter? The adapter class is in module_A, and the SearchActivity, whom use this adapter, in module_A too. And module_A did not dependent on module_B.

Comment: Probably the problem is when inflating R.layout.search_result, IDK how the merged build will handle this